# git: how to apply last updates from dev branch for my older commit?

Tags: git, gerrit

```
dev
|
|
|------------> what should I do to apply that fix and test changes in my commit?
|(commit4:bug fixed)
|------------> git pull, then i've pushed my commit on gerrit (not merged now)
|(commit3:with bug)
|(commit2)
|(commit1)
```

As a solution I can abandon my commit, make `git pull` and then make a new commit. But is there any another solution?

Comment: There are many ways to do, instead of abandoning the commits on gerrit. One is you may use "git pull --rebase" it will automatically try to rebase your commit on the latest changes. Please try this. I will also post other ways as well tonight.

Comment: I was thinking on this combination: when commit is already on gerrit, I reset a head to dev, make pull and then fetch that commit. Also as a possibility (I didn't try it) is: cherry-pick

Comment: I have posted your solution, let me know if you still face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good practice to abandon changes everytime.

You can try below combination (which you thought):

Once you push a change to gerrit and want to update the code to latest, just try

`git reset --hard HEAD~1` (if pushed only 1 change or reset with your branch HEAD).

And do `git pull` and finally use the gerrit change link to Cherry-pick the same to your local system

```
git fetch ssh://gerrit-url/project refs/changes/*/*****/* && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

Try to resolve conflicts if any and you are done. Enjoy!!